# Java Rest service - respond accepted and process requestbehind

Tags: java, rest

I would like to write a java rest service which accept the request, respond immediately with 200 or 202 and process the request behind the scene. the user doesnt have to wait for the whole process to be completed. please suggest

**my rest controller class**

```
 @Override
  public Response generateReport(Request requst) {
     return service.generateReport(requst);
  }
```

**Service class :**

```
@Override
@Async
public Response generateReport(Request requst) {
     generateReport(requst);
     return Response.ok().build();
  }


public void generateReport(Request requst) {
    <!-- login to process the request. it will take 15 mins to complete -->
  }
```

Comment: Not Sure why would you do this, what if the request behind the scene fails? Still you can use HEAD to achieve such stuff.

Comment: when we process the request , will store the status of the request in DB, user can see the status of the request later point of time. since request may take 15 mins to complete.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you want to process an asynchronous request, here is what I would do.

On receiving a Original request, you can create a new resource, and return status code 202(Accepted) with a representation of the new resource.

The purpose of this resource is to let a client track the status of the asynchronous task. Design this resource such that its representation includes the current status of the request and related information such as a time estimate.

When the client submits a GET request to the task resource, do one of the following depending on the current status of the request:

Still processing - Return response code 200 (OK) and a representation of the task resource with the
current status.
On successful completion - Return response code 303 (See Other) and a Location header containing a URI of
a resource that shows the outcome of the task.

On task failure - Return response code 200 (OK) with a representation of the task resource informing
that the resource creation has failed. Clients will need to read the body of the representation to find the reason for failure.

Comment: u have any reference for this. i tried to use Async and it is happening only for the first request .

Comment: with above code. first request works good. second request do not reach service class